# How to load data from Rapid Miner to neo4j ? what are the possible options and operators available?

Tags: neo4j

which operator to use while loading data from Rapid Miner to neo4j

what  operators can be used?

Answer (score 0):

https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/36711/connecting-neo4j-graph-database-to-rapidminer

You can tell us if it works or not.

Comment: Actually, I have already extracted the data from Neo4j in RapidMiner by setting up the JDBC connection and by using “Read Database” Operator. Now I want to load data from Rapid Miner into Neo4j. The Scenario is: I have 2 tables, and we must use these two tables simultaneously and insert the data into neo4j for creating nodes and its relationship. What are the possible options or which operator can we use to do this task. Do let me know if there is anything you know on this. Thanks